# Can blender export vector images?

Tags: export, svg

Can you export a blender curve into a vector image? Is there perhaps an addon that can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [freestyle-svg-exporter](https://github.com/folkertdev/freestyle-svg-exporter) can do that.

Try this:

- In Object Mode, select the object.
- Go to Object > Convert > Grease Pencil
- Go to File > Export > Grease Pencil as SVG
- Save the vector file where desired.